# Как создать свое зарезервированное слово?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Модуль asyncio позволяет писать такое

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')
```

Возможно ли сделать такое с помощью библиотек?Если да, как мне сделать что-нибудь похожее(на C/C++, лучше на C)?

Comment: *"в самом python нет такого слова как async"*, — есть и уже зарезервировано.

Comment: Это называется многопоточное программирование.

Comment: @nomnoms12, согласен, странно, ранее я получал ошибку об отсутствии , ну да не суть, вопрос в другом, можно ли сделать такое же слово, библиотекой?

Comment: @becouse оно к многопоточному не имеет никакого отношения, по умолчанию asyncio работает в одном потоке

Comment: @ИванКакуркин «сделать такое же слово, библиотекой» — нельзя

Comment: @becouse асинкио однопоточный)

Comment: Это реализация блокировки ресурсов, согласен.

Comment: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax